# How to compare the output of ser.readline() in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing code that interfaces between a Raspberry Pi 2 Model b and an Arduino Uno, and I'm unable to get a positive response from comparing the output from ser.readline() to a variable. Below is the code snippet from my Raspberry pi code, where 'u' is just the command I'm sending to the arduino for it to interpret, which I've been able to confirm it can successfully interpret it.

```
while 1:
   time.sleep(1)
   ser.write(u.encode('utf-8'))
   print('ACK sent')
   res = ser.readline()
   if res = 'ON':
      print('Pass')
   else:
      print('Try again')
```

On the arduino all I'm sending as a response to the ser.write(command) is

```
Serial.write("ON\n")
```

No matter what I use to compare the two values the Pi always prints 'Try again', even though when I print the res value, it clearly prints 'ON'.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The `readline` method returns a string with a newline character at the end, so you should either compare it to a value with a newline character at the end, or strip the newline character from the string before you make comparisons:

```
if res == 'ON\n':
```

or:

```
res = ser.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: I tried both and I'm still getting the fail condition. Is there a way to test what type of variable you are working with in python? My best guess at this point is that the arduino is sending an int/ binary data instead of a string to the pi, but I can't imagine why the '==' would still result in a fail

Answer (score 0):

By checking to see if the answer was in the substring of the read value I was able to get it to work:

```
while 1:
time.sleep(1)
ser.write(u.encode('utf-8'))
print('ACK sent')
res = ser.readline()
result = res.find('ON')
if result > -1:
    print('Pass')
else:
    print('Try again')enter code here
```